# java.lang.NullPointerException Error in Data Driven Framework - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

I've created an object for a class in the main function. When I'm calling out a method using that object I'm getting

> java.lang.NullPointerException

What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String...strings) throws IOException{
    String filepath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\testData";
    System.out.println("Filepath is "+filepath);
    Data_Driven_Excel objxl=new Data_Driven_Excel();
    objxl.readExcel(filepath,"TestCaseSuite_v2.xlsx","Changelog");
}
```

**readExcel code**

```
    public void readExcel(String filepath,String filename,String sheetname) throws IOException{
    File xlfile=new File(filepath+"\\"+filename);
    FileInputStream xlInputStream=new FileInputStream(xlfile);
    Workbook SRWorkbook=null;
    String xlFileExtension=filename.substring(filename.indexOf("."));
    if (xlFileExtension.equals(".xlsx")){
        SRWorkbook=new XSSFWorkbook(xlInputStream);
    }
    else if(xlFileExtension.equals(".xls")){
        SRWorkbook=new HSSFWorkbook(xlInputStream);
    }
    Sheet SRSheet=SRWorkbook.getSheet(sheetname);
    int rowcount=(SRSheet.getLastRowNum()-SRSheet.getFirstRowNum())+1;
    for(int i=0;i<rowcount;i++){
        Row row=SRSheet.getRow(i);
        for(int j=0;j<row.getLastCellNum();j++){
            System.out.print(row.getCell(i).getStringCellValue()+"||");

        }
    System.out.println();
    }
   }
```

Comment: Hello. Please [edit] your question with the stacktrace

Comment: From the code snippet you posted, `String filepath=System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\testData";` will throw that exception if the path you specified in `System.getProperty(...)` does not exist.

Comment: But that path do exist....

Comment: I'm suspecting that exception might be in `objxl.readExcel)` method. Can you please share the code snippet for `readExcel` method?

Comment: Code looks fine. Check if filepath is read correctly from the properties file. Also, print `filepath+"\\"+filename` in readExcel method and see if you get correct file path.